# Can i run all my sql script without query by query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My code has multiples queries used for creating tables and stored procedures and I used to create those stuff running one by one, but I would like to know if I can run all of those queries pressing run simply.

I guess my code is not important now, but i add it in case of (a chunk of it):

```
set timezone to 'America/Santo_Domingo';


CREATE TABLE "role" (
  "role" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  "description" varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY ("role")
    
);

CREATE TABLE "member" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "email" varchar  NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  "role" varchar NOT NULL,
  "date" date,
  PRIMARY KEY ("email"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_member.role" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("role")
      REFERENCES "role"("role")
);

CREATE TABLE "membership" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "email_member" varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "type" varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GRATIS',
  "started" date,
  "finished" date,
  "status" varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_membership.email_member"
        FOREIGN KEY ("email_member")
            REFERENCES "member"("email"),
    
    CONSTRAINT "FK_membership.type"
        FOREIGN KEY ("type")
            REFERENCES "type_membership"("type")
);

CREATE TABLE "type_membership" (
  "type" varchar UNIQUE,
  "price_month" int,
  PRIMA
```

How can I run all this code once time? (obviously, if it is possible)

That's PostgreSQL code.

Thanks, experts!

Comment: Which IDE? pgAdmin has a button for this.

Comment: Yup, i'm using pgAdmin and vscode's extension

Comment: Why not try it and see.

Comment: i tried to run it like that but i got an error: "ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"".

Comment: It is very easily possible to run several SQL statements in a single transaction. Looks like you have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I needed to remove some queries like "DROP" inside my code lol. That's why I couldn't execute all script. But thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all statements are terminated with a semi-colon, then the "Execute pgScript" button in pgAdmin should run all statements.

[image]